# About plotting candlestick chart in winapp c#

Tags: charts

I am trying to plot a chart using chart control in dot net winforms application. The datasource I have provided to chart control but after executing code that control goes blank, It is not showing any kind of data or even x and y axis. Anyone who has knowledge about plotting candlestick chart in c# winapp plz help if I'm going wrong in doing it. Here is code which I am using to plot the chart.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
chart1 = new Chart();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "connectionString";
con.Open();
string sql = "Select * from tablename ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter();
sa.SelectCommand = cmd;
sa.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
chart1.Series.Clear();
chart1.Series.Add("new");
chart1.Series["new"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;
chart1.Series["new"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
chart1.Series["new"].XValueMember = "Xval";
chart1.Series["new"].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
chart1.Series["new"].YValueMembers = "High, Low, Open, Close";
chart1.DataSource = dt;
chart1.DataBind();
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
chart1.Series["new"].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chart1.Series["new"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
chart1.Series["new"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Green,
PriceUpColor=Red";
chart1.ChartAreas.Clear();
chart1.ChartAreas.Add("newArea");
chart1.ChartAreas["newArea"].Axes[0].Title = "Date";
chart1.ChartAreas["newArea"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
chart1.ChartAreas["newArea"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;             
chart1.ChartAreas["newArea"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;             
chart1.ChartAreas["newArea"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;             
chart1.ChartAreas["newArea"].AxisY.Maximum = 210;             
chart1.DataManipulator.IsStartFromFirst = false;
```

Comment: Geez, please read on how to format your questions...

Comment: Anyone knows plz provide answer. I am on deadline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following line from code.
chart1 = new Chart();